# While passing the string to a api payload "\" is coming in the payload in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to pass a string variable to my api payload but after passing the payload in my payload data the \ is coming. And also some characters also missing.

```
var blocklyApiResponse = await apiProvider.getapiresponse(
    "private/wiziot-request/", json.encode("$payload"));
print("Response of  Blockly API : ${blocklyApiResponse}");
print("TheAPIPayload: $payload");
```

This is the API I am passing :

```
{"mode":"MULTI_WRITE","api":"smartlight","type":"strip_effects","effect":"vibgyor","device_id":"001_prdt_kp01","source":"BLOCKLY"}
```

This the output after passing the payload :

```
{\\"mode\\":\\"MULTI_WRITE\\",\\"api\\":\\"smartlight\\",\\"type\\":\\"strip_effects\\",\\"effect\\":\\"vibgyor\\",\\"device_id\\":\\"001_prdt_kp01\\",\\"source\\":\\"BLOCKLY\\""
```

Note: some characters also missing.

Comment: issue is with ENCODING . please check again!

Comment: same way only my other api also working.

Comment: You need to share the code where you assign the value to `payload`.